# Density reduction in a two component object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, density, volume

I have a metal object with a mass of 1.374 g, a Volume of 0.315 cm3, and a density of 4.362 g/cm3. I have a buoyant material with a density of 0.609 g/cm3. How do I calculate the amount of buoyant material needed to bring it and the metal object to a combined density of water, or 1 g/cm3?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jonas. Thank you for the reference. I understand the reasoning, and agree. My apology. Will not happen again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this one with a bit of algebra. Let $x$ be the volume of the buoyant material in $cm^2$. Since the total density is the total mass devided by the total volume, we have the equation $\frac{1.374+0.609x}{0.315+x}=1$.

We can then convert it to an easier to work with equation by multiplying both sides with $0.315+x$, which would give us $1.374+0.609x=0.315+x$. Then we could move all the $x$ terms to the right hand side and the constant terms to the left hand side, giving us $1.059=0.391x$. You can solve from there by dividing both sides by 0.391.

Comment: Thank you Masimatutu! Very grateful for your help. Cheers!